# Creating Installer in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, clickonce, sql-server-express

I wanted to deploy my application which uses crystal reports and SQL Server express.
How can create an installer which can create the databases and configure the app.config files on installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClickOnce will not allow you to easily run db scripts upon installation.  You will have to use a VS Setup project or a tool like InstallShield that provides much more control over the install process..